# Error: Syntax error. Missing ')' -

Tags: formula

I wrote a formula for a field Target per Month per Opportunity owner that should populate with currency when an opportunity has a certain close date month.

```
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0X4QAK, MONTH(CloseDate)=1) ,139.043,  
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0X4QAK, MONTH(CloseDate)=2) ,141.617,  
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0X4QAK, MONTH(CloseDate)=3) ,149.341,  
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0X4QAK, MONTH(CloseDate)=4) ,164.791,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0X4QAK, MONTH(CloseDate)=5) ,180.240,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0X4QAK, MONTH(CloseDate)=6) ,185.390,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0X4QAK, MONTH(CloseDate)=7) ,200.839,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0X4QAK, MONTH(CloseDate)=8) ,195.690,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0X4QAK, MONTH(CloseDate)=9) ,218.862,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0X4QAK, MONTH(CloseDate)=10) ,226.588,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0X4QAK, MONTH(CloseDate)=11) ,244.611,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0X4QAK, MONTH(CloseDate)=12) ,205.987,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0QGQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=1) ,64.896,  
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0QGQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=2) ,66.098,  
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0QGQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=3) ,69.703,  
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0QGQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=4) ,76.914,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0QGQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=5) ,84.124,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0QGQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=6) ,86.528,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0QGQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=7) ,93.739,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0QGQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=8) ,91.335,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0QGQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=9) ,102.151,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0QGQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=10) ,105.756,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0QGQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=11) ,114.169,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0QGQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=12) ,96.142,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0XOQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=1) ,28.338, 
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0XOQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=2) ,28.914,  
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0XOQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=3) ,30.491,  
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0XOQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=4) ,33.645,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0XOQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=5) ,36.800,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0XOQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=6) ,37.851,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0XOQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=7) ,41.005,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0XOQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=8) ,39.954,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0XOQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=9) ,44.685,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0XOQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=10) ,46.262,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0XOQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=11) ,49.942,
IF( AND( Owner.Id = 0054J000001U0XOQA0, MONTH(CloseDate)=12) ,42.057,
            0
)))))))))) )))))))))) ))))))
```

Comment: You should use `CASE()` as Adrian suggested, but also use a text editor like the free Visual Studio Code that will do parentheses matching.

Comment: chrome plugin salesforce.com enhanced formula editor is handy too

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I recommend you use `Owner.Name` rather than `Owner.Id` (which you could have made just `OwnerId`). Never use hard coded ids. Migrating this formula between orgs would be at best an annoyance. My second recommendation is that you make use of `CASE` statements to dramatically simplify the syntax. My third recommendation is to use indentation to make opening and closing brackets exceedingly clear.

```
CASE(
    Owner.Name,
    "Person A", CASE(
        MONTH(CloseDate),
        1, 139.043,
        2, 141.617,
        ...,
        0
    ),
    "Person B", CASE(
        ...
    ),
    "Person C", CASE(
        ...
    ),
    0
)
```

Comment: Hierarchy custom setting would work based on the current user right and not on the owner of the record. But yeah that was a good idea :)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Good point.